# Where can I find the descriptions of data types from 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#'

Tags: xml, semantic-web, protege, linked-data, protege4

I am using protege to a create semantic model that uses the
data types from the namespace http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#.

When I analyzed the DataType list I saw two types that are more or less the same:
http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime and the http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTimeStamp.

[image]

So I was determined to find out the differences between them, but the problem is I couldn't find the descriptions/definitions anywhere.

Can anybody give me a link where I can see the document that contains the definitions of these two data types? Or are they not supported anymore?

I navigated to http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema# and to https://www.w3.org/2009/XMLSchema/XMLSchema.xsd but I could not find the definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you wrote up this question, the namespaces, e.g., `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#` became hyperlinks.  If you click on that link, i.e., visit http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#, there are links at the bottom of that page, in the section labeled **Normative References**, that include:

[W3C XML Schema Definition Language (XSD) 1.1 Part 2: Datatypes](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/)

which is the document where the datatypes are defined.  For instance, [**dateTime**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#dateTime), and [**dateTimeStamp**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#dateTimeStamp).  As to the actual differences between them (emphasis added):

> #### [3.3.7 dateTime](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#dateTime)
>
> dateTime represents instants of time, **optionally marked with a
>   particular time zone offset**.  Values representing the same instant but
>   having different time zone offsets are equal but not identical.

> #### [3.4.28 dateTimeStamp](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#dateTime)
>
> The dateTimeStamp datatype is ·derived· from dateTime
>   by giving the value required to its explicitTimezone facet. The result
>   is that **all values of dateTimeStamp are required to have explicit time
>   zone offsets** and the datatype is totally ordered.

So a dateTime has seven properties, but one of them, the time zone offset, is optional.  A dateTimeStamp is like a dateTime, except that the time zone offset is mandatory.

Comment: In your answer you pointed me to the "human readable definition". Is there a machine readable definition of these two data types like an xml, xml/rdf file or something? I'm hopping it should be... Because if there isn't what's the point a of associating values with URIs like http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime ?

Comment: @whitefang well, part of the point of having a URI as an identifier is that now there's a canonical way to reference what type of value you're taking about.  I don't know whether there's a machine readable version or not, but it would not surprise me if there is.

Answer (score 1):

The official definitions of the two data types are at

http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#dateTime

http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#dateTimeStamp

respectively.

Answer (score 0):

With a [`dateTime`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#dateTime) a time zone identifier is optional, [`DateTimeStamp`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#dateTimeStamp) is derived from this and differs in that the time zone is mandatory.